# Can't find most frequent word

Tags: c

Hey this is my first post here. i have been assigned with an excercise to count the most frequent word in c programming language. first and foremost i need to read a number which tells me how many words i will have to read. then i need to use calloc with max element size 50. after that i read the strings. my original idea was to create a one-dimensional array which im gonna later sort alphabetically and then counting and printing the most frequent word would be easy. but after some hours of research i found out i need to use a two-dimensional array and things went out of control. ive been studying computer science for 3 months now and this exercise seems tough. do u have any other suggestions?. the example was this:

```
10
hello
world
goodbye
world
thanks
for
all
hello
the
fish
```

hello
my code so far is

```
int main()
{
   int i, n, j, temp;
   int *a;

   printf("Eisagete to plhthos twn leksewn:");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   a = (int*)calloc(n,50);
   printf("Eisagete tis %d lekseis:\n",n);
   for( i=0 ; i < n ; i++ )
   {
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   }

  for (i = 0 ; i < ( n - 1 ); i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
    {
      if (a[j] > a[j+1])
      {
        temp   = a[j];
        a[j]   = a[j+1];
        a[j+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

dont mind the printfs they are in greek and they are just there to make it look better. i also want to point out that this version is used for integers and not for strings just to start off.
im currently trying a linear search but im not sure if it will help

Comment: You can't read in integers from string(s) like that; try adding an atoi call. `#include <stdlib.h>` and then use `int atoi(const char *nptr);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. There are other very closely related questions (such as [Read text file and output number of words, distinct words, and most frequent word used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106830/read-text-file-and-output-number-of-words-distinct-words-and-most-frequent-wor?rq=1) listed under 'Related') that may well help you.  And I'd lay odds that isn't the only such question on SO.

Comment: Could you please state exactly what happens when you run this code? You seem to be sorting the array of integers, but where are you counting the occurrences?

Comment: Have you learned about`struct`? This would be a good use of `typedef struct { char word[SIZE]; int count } word_t;`

Comment: Are you missing a vowel here, `twn`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Are you sure you should be teaching the guy his own language?

Comment: i havent began the counting,as that is the easy part. my problem is that i can use alloc and sort the array perfectly was it for integers. but with strings thats another case. i cant find a way to read and then sort the strings

Comment: @tripleee Probably not.  However, maybe I should complain to you that three `e`s back to back in a name are too many. ;-)

Comment: @tripleee 
this is greeklish its greek written with latin characters. sometimes when a greek character is resembled with a latin one we use that. for example w here stands for ω (omega) as in greek we have two types of o

Comment: @Pyrromanis Thanks for the clarification, even though it's off on a tangent.

Comment: @Pyrromanis If you're sorting the string array, have you thought about using `qsort`?

Comment: i would like to thank everyone for trying to help but the deadline is in less than half an hour so im just gonan try make the counter and attempt one last time to fix it. i will try and review all the answers i havent so far, but this will happen after the holidays. thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, the code you show is related to reading and sorting integers; it is only loosely related to the word counting problem.

How would you count the occurrences of each number?  You'd have to

- Read the next number;
- If you already have a tally for the number, you add one to the tally for that number;
- If you've not seen the number before, you create a tally for it and set its count to one.
- When all the numbers are read, you search through the set of tallies, looking for the one with the largest count.

  - Record the number and count of the first entry.
  - For each subsequent entry:
  - If the count is larger than the current maximum, record the new maximum count and the entry.
- Print the information about the number with the largest count and what that count is.

Replace numbers with words and the general outline will be very similar.  You might allocate storage for each string (distinct word) separately.

It is easy to count the number of distinct words or the total number of words as you go.  Note that you do not need to store all the words; you only need to store the distinct words.  And the count at the front of the list is computer science education gone astray; you don't need the count to make it work (but you probably have to live with it being in the data; the simplest thing is to ignore the first line of input since it really doesn't help very much at all).  The next simplest thing is to note that unless they're fibbing to you, the maximum number of distinct words will be the number specified, so you can pre-allocate all the space you need in one fell swoop.

Comment: thank you so much for answering. your answer is really helpful and i think this alternative may be better.but due to the fact that i must submit the project in less than half an hour im not able to rewrite the code in time. but i will try to use what you said maybe after christmas, because im not gonna study anymore in the holidays. thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Store your words in a 2D array the loop through it and each time you take a word loop through it again starting from the current index and check if there is an equal. ech time the child loop ends check if the number of occurrences is bigger than the last maximum.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, occurrence=0, maximum = 0;
    char *index_max = NULL;
    char wl[10][10] = {"hello","world","goodbye","world","thanks","for","all","hello","the","world"};

    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        occurrence = 0;
        for (j=i; j<10; j++){
            if (!strcmp(*(wl+i), *(wl+j))){
                occurrence++;
            }
        }
        if (occurrence>maximum){
            maximum = occurrence;
            index_max = *(wl+i);
        }
    }
    if (index_max != NULL){
        printf("The most frequent word is \"%s\" with %d occurrences.\n", index_max, maximum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an O(N*N) or O(N^2) algorithm which works fine for a few dozen words, but is disastrous for even a few hundred, let alone thousands or millions of words. At worst, it should be doable in O(N*logN) time, I believe (log-time lookup for each of N words).

Comment: What I outlined in my answer, put succinctly.  As I said, what you've got works OK for a few words, but if the list of words grows, it becomes dreadfully slow.  The logarithmic time search requires some sort of binary search (a heap, perhaps); the rest is linear rather than quadratic.

Comment: I think this enagh for him as he is a beginner. he can't handle perfermance issue while he still strugling with basics. In both cases he's just trying to send his project not to learn.